# Data pattern visualization using R

Tags: r, data-science

I have a table like

```
    0.5625  0.037037037 0.009923785
0.7734375   0.0781893   0.009923785
0.9609375   0.127572016 0.009923785
0.26953125  0.008230453 0.009923785
0.85546875  0.144032922 0.009923785
0.873046875 0.187928669 0.009923785
0.969726563 0.138545953 0.009923785
0.711914063 0.031550069 0.009923785
0.588867188 0.066300869 0.009923785
0.670898438 0.038866027 0.009923785
0.331054688 0.004572474 0.009328358
0.670898438 0.038866027 0.009923785
0.8203125   0.1015625   0.009923785
0.794921875 0.115234375 0.009923785
0.947265625 0.228515625 0.009923785
0.284179688 0.032226563 0.009923785
0.987304688 0.079101563 0.009923785
0.485351563 0.081054688 0.009923785
0.584960938 0.012695313 0.009288663
0.485351563 0.081054688 0.009923785
0.862048458 0.112664883 0.00996348
0.844804516 0.126747993 0.00996348
0.859089866 0.072807892 0.00996348
0.069334708 0.013713014 0.00996348
0.515944115 0.001011122 0.009288663
0.787155502 0.089283342 0.009923785
```

I want to visualize the data in such a way that center point should be the result data and it should be connected to all those points which have provided that result((example 0.009288663 is generated by (0.515944115, 0.001011122) and (0.485351563, 0.081054688) so 0.009288663 should be connected to (a1,b1) and (a2,b2)).

In the bellow. resembles the results.

```
             (a2,b2)<-----.------------>(a1,b1)
```

I have tried using following code:

```
scatterplot3d(x = test$A, # x axis
            y = test$B,  # y axis
            z = test$Result,         # z axis
            x.ticklabs = levels(test$A),
            y.ticklabs = levels(test$B))
```

1st Approach:
But what I realized, that above method is going to result in plotting 2 points in the 3D plane, instead of the way I needed.

2nd Approach:
I tried plotting all the points and based on condition tried connecting them, that can be like a workaround but still, I couldn't able to figure of the placeholder for the result.

Any help with the query will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a larger subset of your data (maybe using `dput`) so that the problem is reproducible? Thanks :)

Comment: Do you just want to plot A & B or are you trying to represent result as well?

Comment: @G5W: i need results as well.

Comment: @mysteRious : As requested i have updated my table accordingly

Comment: Are the first two columns your a-coordinates and b-coordinates? What is the third column?

Comment: @mysteRious : A and b are just points and the third column are results obtained by an apply formula using A and B points.  The main agenda is to study the relationship between points.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean? Note that I only read in the first two columns with `[,1:2]` here, but it should work even if you read in the full dataset:

```
> library(dplyr)
> library(tibble)
> test <- as_tibble(read.table("yourdata.txt",header=TRUE))[,1:2]
> test
# A tibble: 26 x 2
       A       B
   <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 0.562 0.0370 
 2 0.773 0.0782 
 3 0.961 0.128  
 4 0.270 0.00823
 5 0.855 0.144  
 6 0.873 0.188  
 7 0.970 0.139  
 8 0.712 0.0316 
 9 0.589 0.0663 
10 0.671 0.0389 
# ... with 16 more rows
```

Create columns containing the midpoints of the x's and midpoints of the y's:

```
> test %>% mutate(xdiff=((A+lag(A))/2),ydiff=((B+lag(B))/2))
# A tibble: 26 x 4
       A       B  xdiff   ydiff
   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 0.562 0.0370  NA     NA     
 2 0.773 0.0782   0.668  0.0576
 3 0.961 0.128    0.867  0.103 
 4 0.270 0.00823  0.615  0.0679
... the rest are truncated
```

And then feed all the center points to a plot:

```
> test %>% mutate(xdiff=((A+lag(A))/2),ydiff=((B+lag(B))/2)) %>% 
        ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x=xdiff,y=ydiff))
```

[image: centerpoints]

You can even draw the segments that created the points by adding `geom_segment` but you're going to have to spend some time coming up with a creative color strategy, because it kind of makes the plot look messy:

```
> test %>% mutate(xdiff=((A+lag(A))/2),ydiff=((B+lag(B))/2)) %>% 
        ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x=xdiff,y=ydiff)) +
        geom_segment(aes(x=A,y=B,xend=lead(A),yend=lead(B)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the problem statement is:" I want to visualize the data in such a way that center point should be the result data and it should be connected to all those points which have provided that result (example 0.009288663 is generated by  (0.515944115, 0.001011122) and (0.485351563, 0.081054688) so 0.009288663 should be connected to (a1,b1) and (a2,b2) " I hope example will help with problem statement .

Comment: The bottom plot connects (a1,b1) and (a2,b2) and puts a point at the center of that line segment for each pair of rows in the dataset. That's not what you're asking for?